# Обновление источника изображения на View

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

На `Xaml` странице есть `Image` в который закидывается изображение, которое выбрал пользователь. Как я понял мне нужно реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Вот что я сделал:

XAML

```
 <Image Grid.Row="1"
  Grid.Column="1" 
  x:Name="OriginalImg"
  Source="{Binding Original}"
  DataContext="{StaticResource PickCommand}"/>
```

C#

```
    public Image OriginalImage;
    public Image FilteringImage;
    public Image Original
    {
        get { return OriginalImage; }
        set
        {
            OriginalImage.Source = OriginalBitmap;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }  


 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Но мои свойства принимают значение только при запуске и больше на изменение источника не реагируют. Что не так? И какой `propertyName` нужно указывать?

Comment: А почему ваш setter не использует value никак?

Comment: Так а что он должен с ним сделать? Мне же нужно присвоить новое значение, что я вроде и делаю

Comment: Нужно присвоить новое значение — да. А теперь внимание, вопрос: **какое именно** значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно используют базовые классы, которые добавляют эту реализацию по умолчанию (к примеру ViewModelBase от GalaSoft)

По факту реализация в вашем случае выглядит вернно :). Т.е.
Смотри,

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null) //[CallerMemberName] означает, что вызывающий вставит сюда имя метода.
{
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

т.е. в вашем случае это равносильно:

```
  public Image Original
    {
        get { return OriginalImage; }
        set
        {
           if(OriginalImage.Source != value)
           {
             OriginalImage.Source = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("Original");
           }
        }
    }  


 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

но в общем случае это не совсем правильно.
Последний метод принято оформлять примерно так:

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
{
    var handle = PropertyChanged;
    if(handle != null)
      handle(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: Не может имплементация ТС в принципе быть верной: он игнорирует `value` в сеттере.

Comment: OriginalImage.Source = value;     Только без Source работает

Answer (score -1):

Можно не писать свои велосипеды, а воспользоваться готовым решением https://github.com/demigor/kindofmagic
Написать такой код и при присваивании свойству нового значения всё будет работать.

```
[Magic]
public Image Original {get; set}
```

А что касается вашей ошибки, то в `OnPropertyChanged()` надо передавать новое значение.

Comment: Я бы поспорил в полезности такого сокращения. Особенно в части отладки и связных свойств. Есть элегантные решения под это? Кстати, почему не PostSharp?